# Working with power pivot measures based on Access database?

Tags: ms-access-2010, powerpivot, powerbi

It is possible to create context aware measures in Power Pivot. This is very powerful.

If I want to create reports in Excel based on an Access database, can I use something similar to measures from Access or do I need to go via Power Pivot to get that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet is to use Power Pivot measures.  You'll need to load the data from the Access database into excel anyways, so just build the measures in Power Pivot.